# Removing rows from grouped data after an event has occurred

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data set containing ID, Date, and event. Event is a binary outcome variable. 
There can only ever be a max of one event per ID. The event may be followed by more 0's. I want to remove all zeroes that appear after the event by group. I have a solution using dplyr below but am interested to know if there is a better method. What is a good way of indicating that an event has occurred at some point in the past?

```
library(dplyr)
d <-as.Date("01-05-15", "%d-%m-%y")
#Starting dataset
df <- data.frame(ID= c(rep(234,4),rep(235,6), rep(237,5)), 
       date = as.Date(c((d-4):(d-1),(d-1):(d+4),(d+1):(d+5)),origin="1960-10-01"),
       event = c(0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0))

#desired result
df[c(1:2,5:14),]

#How can Improve this?
df %>% group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(cumulative = lag(cumsum(event), default = 0)) %>% 
  filter(cumulative <1) %>% 
  select(-cumulative) %>% ungroup
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can try with `dplyr`.  After grouping by 'ID', check whether `all` the elements in 'event' is 0 (`all(event == 0)`) or (`|`) sequence of rows is less than or equal to the index of the first maximum element of 'event' (`row_number() <= which.max(event)`) and use that logical index to `filter` the rows.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   group_by(ID) %>% 
   filter(row_number() <= which.max(event)|all(event==0))
#       ID       date event
#   <dbl>     <date> <dbl>
#1    234 2015-04-27     0
#2    234 2015-04-28     1
#3    235 2015-04-30     0
#4    235 2015-05-01     0
#5    235 2015-05-02     0
#6    235 2015-05-03     0
#7    235 2015-05-04     0
#8    235 2015-05-05     0
#9    237 2015-05-02     0
#10   237 2015-05-03     0
#11   237 2015-05-04     0
#12   237 2015-05-05     1
```

Or a bit more compact option would be a double cumulative sum on the `event` that is equal to 1 and checking whether it is less than 2 in the `filter` call.

```
df %>%
   group_by(ID) %>% 
   filter(cumsum(cumsum(event == 1))<2)
```

---

Or using `data.table`, convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df)`), grouped by 'ID' `if` `all` the element of 'event' is 0, Subset the Data.table (`.SD`) or `else` Subset the Data.table with the rows including from the first to the first maximum element in 'event'.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, if(all(event==0)) .SD else .SD[seq(which.max(event))], by = ID]
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation I was trying to understand the all(event==0) part.